# SyntaxError: super() is only valid in derived class constructors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React, so I'm having an issue with the main class I'm trying to setup. I thought that when you setup a constructor that you need to setup super() to be able to use 'this'.  However, I get this error: "SyntaxError: super() is only valid in derived class constructors".  I am unable to find anyone else having this issue. The class in question is below.

```
class TheClassName extends React.Component {

   contructor(props) {

   super(props);

   this.state = {stuff: Array(10).fill(null), stufftwo: false, stuffthree: 'Stuff'};

}


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the `s` in `constructor`. :-)

Comment: LOL, I just hit a similar typo ("consturtor") and found this. Thank you.